# initialisation of seasonal components in holts-winters

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, prediction, forecasting, data-science

```
I am using the Holts Winters seasonal method (triple exponential smoothening)
```

to make forecasts .I would like to know how do we initialise the seaonal components We have the equation as

Now say my m value is 365 (for my data is daily data 365 days in an year).For determining seasonal component at t=1, I will need the value of seasonal component at time t = -365. Likewise I need seasonal component for t=-364,t=-363,etc.How do I predetermine these values...

Answer (score 0):

Initialization isn't formally defined for Holt Winters, and a variety of techniques have been suggested in the literature. [This post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/hw-initialization/) by Hyndman describes a sensible, effective procedure.

An easy to use python package (that also estimates the period of your data) is `seasonal` (available on PyPI or [here](https://github.com/welch/seasonal)). It includes a Holt-Winters example that sets up level/trend/seasonal components at time t=-1, so that you can begin processing your series with the observation at t=0 (and forecast t=0 from this initial t=-1 state)